# Mail Send in ASP Classic

Tags: asp-classic

I got one error at mail send in asp

Error Type:
Persits.MailSender.4 (0x800A0011)
Access is denied.
/public/Register-Process.asp, line 142

I search google, it is NTFS permission error. How can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

[First result on Google](http://support.persits.com/show.asp?code=PS030721110):

> The current user (such as
>   IUSR_machinename) must have Full
>   Control over the queue directory to be
>   able to create files in it. You can
>   instantly fix this problem by giving
>   Everyone Full Control over the queue
>   directory, then tighten security as
>   appropriate. To change permissions on
>   a folder, right-click on it in Windows
>   Explorer, then select
>   Properties/Security